# Weird behavior script element

Tags: javascript

I'm studying JavaScript, but I wanna do it very well...

I readed some questions, here in StackOverflow, but seems they don't fix my issue.

I tried an example with an external script in Google Chrome v. 31.0.1650.57:

I put the `script` element at the bottom (before the `</body>` tag with the next code:

Code JS:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <h2>Logo</h2>
  </header>
  <script src="js/code.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

It supposed to be that the content shows to me and **later**, the script will be downloaded, parsed and executed. **BUT** that wasn't what happened! The content of the page shows to me only when the script was downloaded and executed (I think that, because it took a lot of time).

So, what really happened?

Is it the author wrong? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Can't downvote yet but what is the <header> tags for if it is HTML???

Comment: @J2D8T It's a HTML5 element

Comment: Are you sure the delay is because of that script? For one it seems incomplete, and an empty loop of 100,000,000 iterations executes practically instantly in any modern computer. Look in the browser's network tools to see where the delay actually is.

Comment: I think your loop blocking the ui thread. Reduce your iterations to 100 and see what happen. BTW, your loop seems incomplete.

Comment: @Juhana the script isn't incomplete. I used an empty loop deliberately. The author says that when you put the script at the bottom of the page, the content has to shows to the user, but that wasn't happend

Comment: @Kaf I think that your comment it's near to the answer... Can you explain me or give me a link, book that explains how the browser download, parse and execute JavaScript code (that's what I need)

Comment: Here is blog about [What is a non-blocking script?](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/08/10/what-is-a-non-blocking-script/)

Comment: @Kaf Oh! NCZ! Great, great author. I'm studying JS from his book. If you want to post an answer, I'm glad to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: That is okay @Falcon.

Answer (score 2):

As per your suggestion, I am repeating my comment as an answer here.

Reason could be your loop is blocking the UI thread. Here are some more details on this blog post, **[What is a non-blocking script?](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/08/10/what-is-a-non-blocking-script/)**